# WPF datagrid template column combobox binding expression error

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, combobox, datagridtemplatecolumn

I have a combobox in a datagrid template.
I have an event trigger on this that calls a command. I have confirmed that the command is calling my function.
When my function returns false, I want to set the background color of the combo box to yellow. It if returns  true, I want it to remain white.

The problem appears to be in the following section:

> "Path=DataContext.ApplicationProfilesCollection[].ValidEnvironment"

In the output window I get:

> "System.Windows.Data Error: 40 : BindingExpression path error: '[]'
>   property not found on 'object' ''ObservableCollection`1'
>   (HashCode=44314665)'.
>   BindingExpression:Path=DataContext.ApplicationProfilesCollection[].ValidEnvironment;
>   DataItem='ProfilesUserControl' (Name=''); target element is 'ComboBox'
>   (Name=''); target property is 'NoTarget' (type 'Object')"

Currently there are 3 items in the collection. Do you know how I get WFP to recognize each one? Does anything go in the "[ ]" in the XAML?
Also - I must adhere to the MVVM pattern.

Please see XAML below.
Thanks for your time,

```
<DataTemplate DataType="models:ApplicationProfile">
<ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource 
                        Mode=FindAncestor,
                        AncestorType={x:Type UserControl}},
                        Path=DataContext.DsnCollection}"
          Validation.ErrorTemplate="{StaticResource ValidationTemplate}"
          SelectedItem="{Binding DataSource, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged,  ValidatesOnDataErrors=True}">
    <i:Interaction.Triggers>
        <i:EventTrigger EventName="SelectionChanged">
            <i:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type UserControl}}, Path=DataContext.ValidateDataSourceCommand}"/>
        </i:EventTrigger>
    </i:Interaction.Triggers>
    <ComboBox.Style>
        <Style TargetType="ComboBox">
            <Style.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type UserControl}}, Path=DataContext.ApplicationProfilesCollection[].ValidEnvironment}" Value="false">
                    <Setter Property="ComboBox.Background" Value="Yellow"/>
                </DataTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </ComboBox.Style>
</ComboBox>
```

Comment: Does an item in the ComboBox, i.e. an item in the DsnCollection, have a ValidEnvironment property? Or where is this property defined?

Comment: you need to show your data model, As exception message shows def your data binding is wrong

Comment: Clearly `[]` isn't a valid thing to write in XAML. Can you clarify what you're trying to do exactly? I believe you need to use a converter, but I'm not sure of what you want to do.

Comment: Thanks for responding. No the DsnCollection does not have a ValidEnvironment property. Only each profile in the ApplicationProfilesCollection does. The entire grid is bound to the ApplicationProfiles Collection. One of the fields in there is the Dsn Name which is selected from a string list DsnCollection. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

`ValidEnvironment` is supposed to a *public* `bool` *property* of an item in the `ItemsSource` collection (`DsnCollection`) that you set to `true`/`false` for each item (`Dsn` or whatever you call it) in the collection.

You can then bind to it like this:

```
<Style TargetType="ComboBox">
    <Style.Triggers>
        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding ValidEnvironment}" Value="False">
            <Setter Property="ComboBox.Background" Value="Yellow"/>
        </DataTrigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

You can't bind a `DataTrigger` to a command because a command doesn't return anything.